# Lambda functions with an indefinite number of arguments

Tags: java, interface, lambda, java-8

I'm trying to pull off something like whats given in the code. I want a lambda expression thats able to accept any function

```
interface ExecuteAnyCode{
    void execute(Object... args);
}

void entry(){
    ExecuteAnyCode a = Math::sin;
    ExecuteAnyCode b = System.out::println;

    a.execute(5);
    b.execute("Hello World")
}
```

but it gives me an errror regarding the arguments in the functions passed to the functional interface. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: The type Math does not define sin(Object[]) that is applicable here

Comment: I don't think you understand how lambdas/method references work.

Comment: I know how lambdas work I just wanted to know if theres any way to do this

Comment: `The type Math does not define sin(Object[]) that is applicable here` I thought that comment was an explanation to why the code doesn't work. Then I noticed it was posted by the OP, and realized that was the error they got.

Answer (score 7):

Your functional interface defines a method that accepts a `Object...`. Whatever method reference you use as an assignment to a variable of that functional interface type must have a matching signature. `Math::sin` does not.

The `ExecuteAnyCode#execute` method allows you to invoke it as

```
ref.execute(1, 2, "3", 4, new Something());
```

What would that do if you had

```
ExecuteAnyCode ref = Math::sin;
ref.execute(1, 2, "3", 4, new Something());
```

What would be passed to `Math.sin`?

The language does not allow what you are trying to do. Lambdas and method references require that this information is known at compile time.